# How to deploy a web app without stop and restart

Tags: go, downtime, rolling-updates

I built the project to binary file and deployed it to server before. and start it with `nohup`. But if I updated my code and rebuild my program. I must to kill the process first, then updated the file and start again.

My problem is:

1. The app must be down with at least few seconds.
2. I must update file manually (login the server, kill process, replace file, and then start it)

Is there anyway to hot update the program, something like PHP? I just need update my code to server by git (or svn or others way). then the server will rebuild app and graceful restart it.

Comment: No. Go is a compiled language, contrary to PHP. You should handle this zero-downtime concern at the deployment level (e.g. with Docker/Kubernetes) rather than at the language level.

Comment: If you're hosting on Linux, you can do graceful zero-downtime deploys using `SO_REUSEPORT`. One library that wraps this up nicely is [seamless](https://github.com/rs/seamless).

Answer (score 4):

Usually you run more than one instance of your web application behind a reversed proxy, eg nginx, or any other load balancer. If the few second downtime is an issue for you then you need to have a HA setup anyway. And in such setup you can do a rolling update, where you are replacing instances one by one.
Quick googling will let you find instructions how to do the deployment eg: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-go-web-application-using-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04